# PHP:: File successfully uploaded (but not)

Tags: php, forms, file, post, upload

Wierd... I'm getting that the file was successfully uploaded but in the real world... nothing is uploaded...

Here is my code :

```
<?php

if
(
    move_uploaded_file
    (
        $_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name'],
        'gangina/'.$uploadedFile=basename($_FILES['myUploadedFile']['name'])
    )
)
{
    echo "The file ".$uploadedFile." has been uploaded";
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="myUploadedFile" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

***Small tweak needed here :)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split this up:

```
if (move_uploaded_file
(
    $_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name'],
    'gangina/'.$uploadedFile=basename($_FILES['myUploadedFile']['name'])
)) {
// ...
```

Instead, do:

```
$uploadedFile = basename($_FILES['myUploadedFile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file
(
    $_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name'],
    'gangina/' . $uploadedFile
)) {
// ...
```

When you do `'gangina/'.$uploadedFile=basename($_FILES['myUploadedFile']['name'])` you're actually appending the *declaration of* `$uploadedFile` to `gangina/`, not the *value of* `$uploadedFile`. So this would in fact be evaluated to something like `gangina/1` because the declaration of `$uploadedFile` succeeds, gives true, which is evaluated to 1.

You also need to check that the webserver (normally user www-data on linux) has the rights to create new files in the `gangina` folder (and that that folder actually exists). Under Windows this usually isn't an issue, unless you installed Xampp under Program Files.

Also have a look at [this example code on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004). That shows how to perform all necessary checks to give more precise feedback to the user when handling a file upload in PHP.

Comment: Still getting an error :

 Warning: move_uploaded_file(gangina/php.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11

Comment: @davidmarko does the gangina folder exist? Try using an absolute path `C:/xampp/htdocs/gangina/` instead, that may help if the server selects the wrong directory.

Comment: when I set "C:/xampp/htdocs/gangina/" I'm getting that the file is successfully uploaded but directory gangina is still empty...

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gangina/'.$_FILES['myUploadedFile']['name']

Comment: @davidmarko it works fine for me on linux. Perhaps xampp isn't configured to allow file uploads. Could you do an `echo $_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name']` and not attempt to move the file? This echo will return a path to the temporary uploads directory. Check if the file exists there (which would mean it's at least uploaded).

Comment: {
  echo $_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
  exit;
//  echo "The file ".$uploadedFile." has been uploaded";
 }
 else
 {
  echo $_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
  exit;
//  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }

Comment: Same Error :  Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:/xampp/htdocs/gangina/php.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 17

Comment: @davidmarko yes, but what is the value of `$_FILES['myUploadedFile']['tmp_name']`? It should be a path to the temporary location of the file. Check if that path exists and if the file is there.

Comment: C:\xampp\tmp\php4E.tmp

Comment: @davidmarko it seems you're constantly missing the second part of my comments. *Check if that path exists and if the file is there*.

Comment: WORKING NOW! PERFECT!

Answer (score 1):

Give your submit button a name e.g. `name="uploadImage"`

```
 <?php 
function uploadImage($image,$ftp_file){
// Path and file name
$imgUrl = "gangina/".$image;
if (file_exists($imgUrl)){
$temp = str_ireplace('gangina/', '', $image);
$imgUrl = "gangina/". rand(1,99999).$temp;
}
$img = str_ireplace('gangina/', ' ', $imgUrl);
 // Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
if(move_uploaded_file($ftp_file, $imgUrl)){
$results = "image successfully uploaded";
   }  else {
   $results = 'Could not upload image'; 
    }
  return $results;
}
 if(isset($_POST['uploadImage']{
    $imgurl = $_FILES['ImageName']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['ImageName']['tmp_name'];
    //uploading image
    uploadImage($imgurl, $temp);

  }

?>
```